# boost::dynamic_bitset slower than std::bitset unless std::bitset is reset

Tags: c++, boost-dynamic-bitset, std-bitset

I recently came across the bitset templates and would really like to use them in my current project.  Reading on, I see that the `std::bitset` template must have a size determined at compile time.  Many suggest using the `boost::dynamic_bitset` to alleviate this requirement.

To compare the two, I decided to do a speed comparison of `set`, `flip`, and `count` methods.

The results are quite odd...and I'm wondering if someone can shed some light on it for me.

The code is at the end of the post, but I'll explain what I'm doing here.  I have one `std::bitset` object (call it `bs`) and one `boost::dynamic_bitset` object (call it `dynbs`).  Each has `n=1000000` bits.  For a given method above, call the method on each of the `n` bits sequentially and repeat this `R=10000` times.

Using the `std::chrono` library, here are the timings for each in nanoseconds:

```
set
        bitset:              267 nsecs
    dyn bitset:      18603174546 nsecs

flip
        bitset:               73 nsecs
    dyn bitset:      18842352867 nsecs

count
        bitset:               77 nsecs
    dyn bitset:               51 nsecs
```

The `boost::dynamic_bitset` seems to be much slower for `set` and `flip`.

To make it more interesting, if the method `reset` is called on the two objects before running these tests, then the timings are comparable.  Here they are:

```
set
        bitset:      19397779399 nsecs
    dyn bitset:      18472863864 nsecs

flip
        bitset:      18599248629 nsecs
    dyn bitset:      18376267939 nsecs

count
        bitset:               68 nsecs
    dyn bitset:               61 nsecs
```

Now, both containers claim to initialize all bits to `0`, thus a call to `reset` shouldn't change any of the bits.  Dumping the output of `none` before and after `reset` does confirm this.

So after all that, I have two questions:

1)  Why is the `boost::dynamic_bitset` so much slower than the `std::bitset` when calling `set` and `flip`?

2)  Why does calling `reset` have a huge negative effect on the speed of `std::bitset`?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
using namespace boost;

int main(){
  const unsigned int n=1000000;
  bitset< n > bs;
  dynamic_bitset< > dynbs(n);
  // bs.reset();
  // dynbs.reset();

  unsigned int i,r,R=10000;
  high_resolution_clock::time_point tick,tock;


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method: set

  std::cout << "set" << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      bs.set(i);

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs" 
       << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      dynbs.set(i);

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "dyn bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs"
       << std::endl << std::endl;


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method: flip

  std::cout << "flip" << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      bs.flip(i);

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs"
       << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      dynbs.flip(i);

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "dyn bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs"
       << std::endl << std::endl;


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Method: count

  std::cout << "count" << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      bs.count();

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs"
       << std::endl;

  tick=high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(r=0; r<R; r++)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      dynbs.count();

  tock=high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << setw(16) << "dyn bitset: " 
       << setw(16) << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tock-tick).count() << " nsecs"
       << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 bitset.cpp -o bitset
```

where `bitset.cpp` is the code inserted above.

Comment: @T.C. So is it just that my tests are too simple?  I guess I'm not quite sure the implications of that.  I tried to read the assembly code, but don't quite get what's going on.

Comment: Pretty much. Microbenchmarks are hard to write. In this case, if you add code to print out, e.g., `bs`, after each loop, then the `set`s and `flip`s probably won't be optimized away. To ensure that the `count` calls won't be optimized out, add the return value to a variable that you then print out. `dynamic_bitset` uses allocation on the heap, and it's much harder for the compiler to prove that the changes made by `set` and `flip` will be invisible.

Comment: @T.C.  Gotcha.  That makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying whats going on under the hood.  Just added some of the things you mentioned and it looks to be a fair fight now!  I'll post a solution quoting what you said and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> 1) Why is the `boost::dynamic_bitset` so much slower than the
>   `std::bitset` when calling set and flip?

Since `std::bitset` does not use dynamic allocation, and your `bitset` is a local variable, the compiler can easily determine that all the `set`'s and `flip`s and `count`s have no externally visible effect. As a result, it [optimizes them all away](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVQyILBAAdzLp5kUAjEbTBbK3DsaKAG4II2dLiFUOqCAAtc6MOjkjOUkEQTkyMTOADmSMMQSYmBCMhxwA3IeNgzFvddvJlq9c7JwbCR6cAAKAEoAbzIkJAg1HCQYMGMTMAQ4JCDzAF4ARgAGYpLnOJ4%2BARRzJBIkLkwypAB6ZvrMADp8fmxIptakOABPMAauqwE%2Bsljk1JB0zOywYJAAGlxVgCUCksKmpXmlAH1u9FhsDDAj6HQIAGsALgeLvSOmdByL%2B9Xpe4CZ1qAoHAkGgsHgiEggFtACyAiU6DgDyQPWmcQcTwSMGCKGqACIenjUNUMQ8EGA4FAAnEvndcgcTMdTudLtcoLdHg91AB3KYzABmMjCuFyeyQuBQm0c4oA1DKIjM4oLcGEQKLpSAUGANXKFXF9e0Oj1VRFqUhfnSGUyrGdsaybvcnjypnEsTiSQJefkAGwRYlIPEVHrIomKg24lGesI%2Bv0RuAwXAEC5qa4EHBahhYSRqOCYEhhC0AWlpEQ6WOWkX9RNSkkwoYN%2BojpPJlLNtPphxONpZKYdnOdpum0MhI9HY7B0KQcOwCKRSH5UGYaJR2CRDzdVYXzCJTdXTxbVOX7atXcwtuTVz7TvQvMHAqFIrFEqlsvlYeVqvV2S1OrfDcNW5MCabYch2jKnue9rso6XI3i68ToNi%2Fo9F6vpVkGAghkgYaNh62CobG1TxomF6pumFjqPwCQUnmBYcsWID3KW5a9IRAbmFRdY4XEu5rgeZrjoJQkjpO06zsiLHLqSG4RniLE7iSe5khSh4zMenbMnavbQf2cF3kqD5fs%2B0q4Lq75CmqYqatq2Rmf%2BYwsXyNKgSemmkVesG3k0Ml4QR6G8MG7HcchUYxv6xFJvaabYBmlHZjR%2BZFiWZaIRWbHVpxeLBbx%2B4qf8cT4NgCZgEgexkAAvkAAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fopt%2Fgcc-4.9.0%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-Wall%20-Wextra%20-pedantic%20-O3%22%7D%5D%7D), and your code basically ends up being a bunch of timing and printing calls.

Note that in the above assembly it doesn't even allocate stack space for the bitset. The whole thing basically vanished without a trace.

`boost::dynamic_bitset` allocates its buffer dynamically with `new`, which ends up calling `::operator new()`, which can be an arbitrary overloaded version defined in a different translation unit. So it's very difficult for the compiler to prove that changes to the buffer returned are not visible externally.

Your `count` loops for both `std::bitset` and `boost::dynamic_bitset` are optimized away because the compiler can easily see that `count()` doesn't change anything in the bitsets and you don't use the return value.

> 2) Why does calling `reset` have a huge negative effect on the speed of
>   std::bitset?

I checked the source code of `reset` in GCC, and it calls a compiler intrinsic `__builtin_memset`, passing it a pointer to the buffer. When you pass a pointer to a stack variable to an external function, then the compiler is much more constrained in what it can remove, since changes in the variable may now be externally observable (for example, the function called could have stored a copy of the pointer somewhere and something can peek into it later).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  That really helps to understand whats going on.  How did you use GCC to look at the source code?  Did you use the `-S` option and look at the assembly code?

Comment: @nick You go look at the contents of the `<bitset>` header :)

Comment: I have asked Boost to add small buffer optimization to dynamic_bitset as well. That would hopefully address the issue that dynamic_bitsets would have similar performance if they are small (yet unknown size). Not sure though if it is picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like T.C. has the explanation.

> All your set and flip (and counts) on bitset are completely optimized
>   out.

A link was provided with the assembly code to show this: [assembly code](http://goo.gl/bixGs9)

By returning the values from the three different methods and adding them to an additional variable did the trick and it seems to be a fair fight now (as suggested by T.C.).